# Apache Tomcat context.xml files

Tags: tomcat

In all the Apache documentation, I can't find a very lucid explanation of, especially the distinctions between, the two *context.xml* files in the installation (of Tomcat 9):

- *conf/context.xml* (I'm not talking about this file in this question.)
- *webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml*
- *webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml*

particularly since the last two come identical before we modify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Introduction)" and "[host-manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/host-manager-howto.html#Introduction)" are just two default web applications shipped with Tomcat.

And each of them has the their own configuration ([context.xml](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html))

Comment: Okay. I could see that these were in the context of two, separate web applications, but, using the Tomcat manager, I was not aware of using two separate manager bits. So, access can be controlled separately to each. Thanks.